My Google Developer Tools cannot display the line numbers of my JavaScript code correctly
I tried the solution provided by Google, which was to open the experiments and disable 'Automatically pretty print in the Source Panel'. However, my version of Chrome does not have this option.
Here is what it looks like unformatted:

Here is what it looks like after formatting:

Here is what my Google Chrome settings look like.

As shown in the picture, my browser does not have this option.
Furthermore, my Google Chrome version is 124.0.6367.207.

Does this answer your question? Human readable javascripts in chrome developer tools

You're after lines numbers of minified JavaScript which is all on a single line. Although the formatted code is shown on multiple lines the source is not. I'm not sure what value the formatted line numbers would give you? The fomatted line numbers are unlikely to match actual line numbers in your source.

How have you formatted the code in the second screenshot? Did you use the little {} button in dev tools? Disabling "Automatically pretty print in the Source Panel" just means you have to manually click it to format the code, nothing more.
